# Regex /A?/g not matching multiple A's

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does the regex `/A?/g` only match a the first capital A in a string?  From what I understand, if I execute the following code

```
reg = /A?/g;
match1 = reg.exec('AaAa');
match2 = reg.exec('AaAa');
match3 = reg.exec('AaAa');
console.log(match1, match2, match3); //["A"], [""],[""]
```

I can't capture the second occurence of "A".  Why?  It seems to me that even though the ? makes A optional, since its greedy, shouldn't it choose to include the second "A" in the 2nd match?

Comment: I don't know, but I always do it the other way around: `"AaAa".match(/A?/g)` shows `["A", "", "A", "", ""]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `exec`, the regular expression object "remembers" the index of the last match.

Lets log the value of `lastIndex`:

```
reg = /A?/g;
reg.exec('AaAa');
console.log(reg.lastIndex); // 1
reg.exec('AaAa');
console.log(reg.lastIndex); // 1
reg.exec('AaAa');
console.log(reg.lastIndex); // 1
```

As you can see, the index of the last match doesn't change! But *why*?

The reason is that your regular expression contains an *optional* match (`?`).

The second time `exec` is called, it tries to match the character at index 1,  `"a"`, with `A?`. That works because `A?` denotes an optional occurrence of the character, i.e. it basically matches the empty string before `"a"`. But that also means that the input character isn't actually consumed and hence the index is not increased. It's a *zero-width* match.

The same process visualized differently:

```
AaAa // does index 0 match "A?" ? Yes, consume "A" and increase index to 1
^
AaAa // does index 1 match "A?" ? Yes, but do not consume "a"
 ^
AaAa // does index 1 match "A?" ? Yes, but do not consume "a"
 ^
...
```

Calling `exec` will just keep matching the second `"a"`.

[Learn more about `exec` in the MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

---

If you make the character *not* optional, it works as you expected it.